# Detect if a table in my database has changed for optimization need

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, database, optimization

I am using Sql Server Compact and am building an MVC app.

When getting my data, many links are made to many tables, which can eventually evolve into complex loops and long loading time due to getting data and making links each time the data loads.

So I've thought that optimizing would be a good idea and one way to do that would have been to check if the data has changed before loading any data. If it's true, then do the total loading, else refer to a data structure actually existing instead.

Is there a way to check if the data has changed in the table of my database? A method, perhaps?

Thank you!

Comment: select the right answer!

Answer (score 2):

As Spyro states in [their answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8643018/mysql-fastest-way-to-check-if-data-in-innodb-table-has-changed/8643198#8643198):

> The simple way is to add a nullable column with type TIMESTAMP, with
>   the trigger:
>
> > ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP.
>
> Therefore, the inserts will not change because the column accepts
>   nulls, and you can select only new and changed columns by saying:
>
> ```
> SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `mdate` > '2011-12-21 12:31:22'
> ```
>
> Every time you update a row this column will change automatically.
>
> Here are some more informations:
>   http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/timestamp.html
>
> To see deleted rows simply create a trigger which is going to log
>   every deletion to another table:
>
> ```
> DELIMITER $$
> CREATE TRIGGER MyTable_Trigger
> AFTER DELETE ON MyTable
> FOR EACH ROW
> BEGIN
>   INSERT INTO MyTable_Deleted VALUES(OLD.id, NOW());
> END$$
> ```

Or you can do a Hash Function(MD5,SHA1) on all the table result and to save it Like `MD5(table);`
if the value of the `MD5(table);` changed the table changed!

```
// Serialize the table
DataContractSerializer serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(DataTable));
MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
XmlWriter writer = XmlDictionaryWriter.CreateBinaryWriter(memoryStream);
serializer.WriteObject(memoryStream, table);
byte[] serializedData = memoryStream.ToArray();

// Calculte the serialized data's hash value
SHA1CryptoServiceProvider SHA = new SHA1CryptoServiceProvider();
byte[] hash = SHA.ComputeHash(serializedData);

// Convert the hash to a base 64 string
string hashAsText = Convert.ToBase64String(hash);
```

Comment: Wow! Fancy! I will dive into this eventually, so that's nice of you to tell me :) I appreciate it!

Comment: Do you know of any way that it could be checked in C# in my Data Class else of the timestamp?

Comment: I add other way in my answer check it!

Comment: If you copy the words of someone else, you must provide proper attribution. I've edited the above to indicate where the first part of your answer was drawn from. In the future, please make sure to do this yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You know, when I was building an off-line solution, where people could change data off-line and then sync it back up at night, I found the best way to make that determination for our configuration data (much like what you're dealing with) was to hold a [`timestamp`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb726005.aspx) in every row. The reason this worked so well is because I could then build a table that indexed those `timestamp` values based off of a simple MAX query against every table. So that table might look like this:

```
CREATE TABLE TimestampIndex (
    TableName SYSNAME PRIMARY KEY,
    LastChange TIMESTAMP
)
```

and then I could run basic queries and populate that table when they went off-line:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT TableName FROM TimestampIndex WHERE TableName = 'Table1')
    UPDATE TimestampIndex SET LastChange = (SELECT MAX(ts) FROM Table1)
ELSE
    INSERT INTO TimestampIndex (TableName, LastChange) SELECT 'Table1', MAX(ts) FROM Table1
```

and then when they came back online I could simply perform something like this:

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT TableName FROM TimestampIndex WHERE TableName = 'Table1' AND LastChange = (SELECT MAX(ts) FROM RemoteDb.dbo.Table1))
BEGIN
    -- there must be changes to make then
END
```

Comment: This is the same principle of my answer?

Comment: @OneManCrew, similar. But keep in mind that I added it at the same time as yours so I wasn't even reading yours. Secondly, your principle is more fine grained whereas mine is at a higher level and would require the OP to reload all configuration if a change existed for a table. It is more performant for constant checking and probably less performant for granual loading of configuration data. However, I found in my experience, that it wasn't loading the data that was the issue, it was loading every single table. However, it's unlikely it requires a downvote from you ;)