# innodb table last modified date

Tags: mysql, innodb

How can I determine last modified date for innodb tables? According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2785429/how-can-i-determine-when-an-innodb-table-was-last-changed) question it seems there is unfixed bug for years. I can't use checksum because I am working with large tables and computing checksums takes too long. And triggers also don't look like the right solution, because I just don't want to write trigger for hundrets of tables. Is there any other way I can achieve this?

I need last modified date for entire table (delete, insert, update), not for single rows.

EDIT:
I think there is no acceptable way for me to determine this without modifying existing queries or creating triggers, so it would be enough just to check if table was modified. As I said this is possible using `CHECKSUM TABLE...`, but it's quite slow for large innodb tables. Is there any better algorithm to achieve this?

Comment: To clarify, you want the last modified date for each row, or for the entire table?

Comment: Good point, I need modified date for entire table, I already edited my question.

Comment: @Peter Krejci are you interested on all types of updates including delete or just update and insert??

Comment: As you said the bug has been opened for the past 7 years http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=14374

Comment: This is not a bug. It's an unimplemented feature that some developers would like to have.

Answer (score 0):

Try create a wrapper procedure which will execute your statement and update the current time.

This answers on your comment:

"This will prevent you from writing trigger for hundred of tables:"

as a result of some error , stuck overflow doesn't lets me to publish an example code of such procedure,

you may "execute" the command without any problem , i have tested it now and it works. you must execute your procedure as a "call my_procedure('insert/update/delete ...')"

```
 PREPARE s1 FROM @sql;
 EXECUTE s1;
 DEALLOCATE PREPARE s1;
```

here is a link on how to create such procedure http://www.java2s.com/Code/SQL/Procedure-Function/EXECUTEdynamicSQLcommand.htm

you need only to change the concatenation to an empty string with your parameter.