# Practical way of finding last update/insert/delete of any table in a database?

Tags: mysql, mariadb, sql-update, last-modified

OS: W10.

This question is specifically about what's possible in MariaDB, specially version "Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.7.3-MariaDB".

***Edit***
From [another SO site](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/310972/102949) I have found that from 10.3.4 MariaDB does in fact implement "temporal tables". Not clear yet whether this provides a solution.

I want to implement a way of having a "last modified" timestamp for a database, i.e. which shows when the last INSERT or DELETE or UPDATE occurred, *regardless of the table where it happened*.  I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13403052/595305), which looked promising... but then some comments there about InnoDB and `information_schema.tables.update_time` led me to do an experiment.

Contrary to what is asserted in some places about `update_time` always being `NULL` in InnoDB tables, this does not seem to be the case with what I've got. Unfortunately, the comment there about this value being set to `NULL` whenever the server starts *does* appear to be true.

Elsewhere I read that newer versions of MariaDB, pulling away from vanilla MySQL, do in fact implement some sort of history of changes.

I'm currently working on the assumption that I shall have to implement an `ON_UPATE` trigger for every table, and then get values for each of these and find the most recent, in order to determine the "last modified" time for the whole database.

Is there any other possibility with this version of MariaDB?

***Edit***
In fact I have provided an answer which works for my use case [on another SO site](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/310988/102949) (when I added this link as an answer here that answer was then deleted by a mod - but in reality some might find it useful).

Answer (score 1):

just make a table that has all the table names and a timestamp column.
then on the `ON_UPATE` trigger, just update the tablename record.

this way, you have central table which has the timestamps, dont do any hacks.

keep it simple.

use [this](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/create-trigger/)

Comment: Thanks. This has the merit that it is conceptually simple, but in practice it requires a lot of triggers: for each table I would have to create a trigger not only for `ON_UPDATE` but also `AFTER_INSERT` and `AFTER_DELETE`.  Actually this extra table need only have one column and one row: all triggers would then update that value.

Comment: .... but you have given me an idea: `information_schema.tables.update_time` is in fact updated whenever any insert/delete/update operation occurs. So I could perhaps set a trigger on that ... to update this additional one-row, one-column table. This would provides a means of making the most recent `update_time` value persistent between server starts...

Comment: ... however this idea of mine is a non-starter, as the only access to `information_schema` is read-only: you can't put a trigger on it, you can't change its privileges in any way, and in fact people say that this is in fact a `VIEW`, not a table.