# Get latest update time of Mysql database with InnoDB tables

Tags: mysql

I want to get the last update time of a MySQL database (on any table - and I don't want to check all tables separately).

I tried

```
select max(Create_time) from (show table status);
```

but MySQL does not like the syntax and Create_time is set to NULL for InnoDB tables. I hope that there is some configuration setting that lets MySQL update Update_time for InnoDB tables.

Comment: Maybe have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2785429/how-can-i-determine-when-an-innodb-table-was-last-changed