# How to get mysql last update/delete/insert datetime for a table?

Tags: mysql

In mysql, how can you get the datetime for the last time a certain table had a row which got deleted or inserted or updated?

Thanks

Comment: omega omega you should know better!!! i see nice badge!!

Answer (score 0):

For a MyISAM table do this:

```
 SELECT UPDATE_TIME FROM   information_schema.tables
     WHERE  TABLE_SCHEMA = 'databasename' AND TABLE_NAME = 'tablename';
```

For innodeb, you're apparently out of luck, since there's been a long standing bug about this... see this question: [How can I determine when an InnoDB table was last changed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2785429/how-can-i-determine-when-an-innodb-table-was-last-changed)